# How to filter by ID in this graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to add a filter to the following graphql query and I'm just not able to figure out where to add the filter parameter. I went through the documentation but I'm clueless how to do it. I should also retain the limit and offset to do the pagination. I would like to filter by ID.

```
const data = await axios.post("http://localhost:1337/graphql", {
        query: `query {
        newsPostsConnection(limit: ${limit}, start: ${start}) {
          values {
            id
            title
            body
            writtenBy
            imageUrl
            created_at
          }
          aggregate {
            totalCount
          }
        }
      }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [link](https://dgraph.io/docs/graphql/queries/search-filtering/) answers your question

Schema

```
type NewsPostsConnection {
    id: String! @id
    title: String!
    body: String
    writtenBy: String
    imageUrl: String
    created_at: DateTime
}
```

Query

```
query {
  getNewsPostsConnection(id: $id) {
    values {
      id
      title
      body
      writtenBy
      imageUrl
      created_at
    }
    aggregate {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I meant how do you add the ID variable to filter?